# MSysGit & CopSSH not appering to locate the id_rsa file on windows server 2008

Tags: ssh, msysgit, copssh

I have an interesting issue where I cannot connect via SSH to to ServerA from ServerB in order to migrate a repository, Over SSH using MSysGit & CopSSH.

I have no problems accessing ServerA & B from other machines. but when I attempt a simple

```
ssh -v git@ServerA "echo something" from ServerB, then I get the following.

OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to ServerA[195.135.3.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ServerA' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

BUT if i specify the id_rsa file specifically, i.e

```
ssh -v2 -i %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa git@wtcsubv "echo something"
```

Then It works and I get this

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to ServerA [195.135.3.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user1\\.ssh\\id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ServerA' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\user1\\.ssh\\id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 532
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending command: echo something
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
something
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.2 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

so i know the keys are fine. but it's as if it cant locate the id_rsa in the .ssh folder unless I tell it specifically where it is.

Am I missing a configuration step that will let it know the location of the keys ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `HOME` is defined to `%USERPROFILE%`, otherwise `CopSSH` might try use `%HOME%/.ssh/...` which ,since `%HOME%` is empty, would result in `/.ssh/...`.

Comment: Thanks, I manged to work that myself through much trial an error !